# what to use in place of NULL in QUEUE made by LINKEDLIST

Tags: java, queue

i came to know that due to AMBIGUITY that can be cause by poll function we are not recommended to use NULL value in a QUEUE made by LINKEDLIST.Then what should be inserted in place of null?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you ever heard about `Null Object Pattern`? This should help you, i think.

Comment: If you can't or don't want to put object with null value to your linked list. Prepare an object which is called NullObject (NullObject class - NullQueueObject / NullQueueElement for example). That object must have specified value that could be easly recognized in your algorithm (some value instead of null in your case) - that object could be skipped, deleted, replaced etc.

Comment: You could define individual behaviour (methods) for that object. If you want more details, check these links [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_object_pattern), [pattern explained](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/null_object). Tell me if it works for your case.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer..
What we can do is to create a Linked list node containing a particular value(for example Integer.MAX_VAL) and use that node as a representation of null type.